# Oracle and execution plans

Tags: oracle, execution-plan

I have used the following procedure to view the last execution plan

```
create or replace procedure display_plan
as
begin
  for c in (select plan_table_output t from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor('', '', 'allstats advanced last'))) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(c.t);
  end loop;
end;
```

With `dbms_xplan.display_cursor` it is possible to specify the SQL_ID. I understand that you can get a list of SQL_IDs from the table `V$SQL` but how does one decide what ones belong to the current session?

Comment: You don't need a procedure for that. Just run the `select` statement directly.

Comment: ... It just makes life a little easier to have it as a procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can specify the SQL_ID.  The usage would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR('gwp663cqh5qbf',0));
```

To find the SQL IDs for the current session, you'll first need to get the SID for your session, and then search v$session for the related SQL_IDs:

```
select sys_context('USERENV','SID') from dual;
select SQL_ID from v$session where SID='yoursid';
```

If the SQL aged out of the cursor cache, you may be able to find it in v$active_session_history:

```
select SQL_ID from v$active_session_history where SESSION_ID='yoursid';
```

I would recommend reading the [manual page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_xplan.htm#ARPLS378) for DBMS_XPLAN to get the full details.

Comment: Is it not better just to look into the `v$active_session_history` table and not bother with the `v$session` table?

Comment: Unless your query runs in a fraction of a second, v$active_session_history  should be fine.  The samples are collected every second, so extremely fast queries could theoretically be missed (although I don't think I've ever seen this happen).